# How react-markdown should use MathJax (react-mathjax)

Tags: typescript, markdown, mathjax, react-markdown

Could you help me please to create react component which can render markdown and which use MathJax.

I used this article [Rendering Markdown and LaTeX in React](https://medium.com/@MatDrinksTea/rendering-markdown-and-latex-in-react-dec355e74119) to solve this problem, but ReactMarkdown now doesn't have such props as renderers. Also rehypeMathJax plugin doesn't work correctly. For example doesn't render correct such instance as

```
\begin{align}
\text{good: } &\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2. \\[1em]
\text{bad: }  &\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^n i)^2.
\end{align}
```

If i use as below it works great, but how i should wrap it into ReactMarkdown component

```
<MathJax.Provider>
    <MathJax.Node inline formula={value || ''} />
    <MathJax.Node formula={value || ''} />
</MathJax.Provider>
```

Please please help!